# How to use angular-pdf directive in Angular 4 to show pdf files

Tags: angular, pdf

I want to use [angular-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-pdf) with Angular 4.
I googled it but did not find any documentation

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciable

Comment: It's angularjs directive not angular

Comment: A quick search shows there is angular2 pdf viewer. You can try it out. https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer

Comment: @Santosh but ng2-pdf-viewer does not have built in zoom in, zoom out and rotate option

Comment: I checked the readme of ng2-pdf-viewer, and you can set the zoom by [zoom]=0.5 and same for rotation ie [rotation]=“90”.

Comment: @Santosh i want zoom in buttons on web page

Comment: You can add your own buttons, and on click of buttons, you can modify the zoom variable... for zoom in you can increase and for zoom out, you can decrease the zoom variable